# Logical AND operation across multiple lists

Tags: python, boolean-operations, elementwise-operations

I have a dictionary that looks something like:

```
d= {'GAAP':[True,True],'L1':[True,False],'L2':[True,True]}
```

I would like to perform a logical AND operation across each of the values in the dictionary and return a **LIST** of True/False values. Something like:

```
for counter in range(0,2):
    print(d['GAAP'][counter] & d['L1'][counter] & d['L2'][counter])
```

My dictionary is fairly large so want to avoid manually typing each of the keys to perform the logical AND.

Comment: Note: Your `&` actually is the bitwise, not logical AND. And also you don't have to type all keys manually, just use the `d.keys()` method (or `d.values()`, as you are only interested in the values anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there builtin functions for elementwise boolean operators over boolean lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770434/are-there-builtin-functions-for-elementwise-boolean-operators-over-boolean-lists). Note that the best answer to your question there is actually in the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use `zip` to get all corresponding elements and then to ask if they are `all` true:

```
map(all, zip(*d.values()))
```

Result it: `[True, False]`

Comment: Very efficient solution! Note that `map(...)` does not return a list, but is lazily evaluated, just like `zip(...)`, so to get a list of the results, you need to wrap `list(...)` around that.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch - that is true. Was contemplating if to add that to the answer or not :)